# C# Unit Testing - Ensure That Loop Continues Until Valid Input is Given

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, console-application

I have the following code that asks the user for input and continues asking until they give valid input.  The user input is received via Console.ReadLine

```
public int ChooseMove() {
        string input;
        do {
            input = ui.AskUserForInput();
        } while (!ValidateInput(input));
        return int.Parse(input);
    }

private bool ValidateInput(string input) {
    string [] positions = ui.GetValidInputs();
    if (Array.Exists(positions, position => position == input)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am trying to unit test the ChooseMove method, but I am stuck.

I have a basic case working in NUnit like this...

```
[Test]
        public void TestValidMove() {
            StringReader consoleInput = new StringReader("6");
            Console.SetIn(consoleInput);
            Assert.That(player.ChooseMove(), Is.EqualTo(6));
        }
```

However, I don't know how to test if the user gives bad input that it continues until valid input is given.

I want to send to the input stream something "52" and then "6" the second time through.  How do I send one input after another using the StringReader?  Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what are you expecting here `ui.GetValidInputs();
`

Comment: Sorry should have been clearer about what ui is... ui.AskUserInput() will just do a Console.ReadLine right now... and ui.GetValidInputs() return a string arrary starting with ["1", "2", "3"], etc. I made it an interface because in the future there may be a GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object that requires direct use of the console is going to be more or less untestable. There's only one console for your process and redirecting it affects the entire process.

A more testable version would use a `TextReader` that you pass into it, perhaps via the constructor. In the actual application, the initialization can pass in Console.In but in your tests you can inject a `StringReader` or other object that allows you to fake the input.

You don't show the relationship between your player and ui objects, but I'm assuming that the player is created with a ui to use. I'd give the ui object a constructor that takes a TextReader so as to make it more testable.

As far as passing multiple inputs through a `StringReader` goes, if you are using ReadLine, then simply put multiple lines into the string, using `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: Will be trying this when I get home!

Comment: This worked for me!

In case anyone comes along later with the same question, using the following code 
`StringReader consoleInput = new StringReader("52" + Environment.NewLine + "8");
Console.SetIn(consoleInput);`
I was able to create consecutive input.  First call to Console.ReadLine() returned 52 and second call to Console.ReadLine() returned 8.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the type of "ui". However, if it were me, I'd inject in an object that would have an array of answers that it would respond to calls to AskUserForInput, say two that do not validate, one that does, followed by a fourth one that also validates.  Then I'd call ChooseMove, and assert that I got the third item.